# Laravel 5.2 Migration: Cannot add foreign key of char data type

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I am trying to create a **nullable foreign key of char data type**. When I run the migrate command. I get the following error. I am not sure, where I am doing wrong.

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `levels` add
>   constraint `levels_sample_type_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`sample_type_id`) references `sample_types` (`id`))
>
> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign
>   key constraint

Here is the migration file contents for levels table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('levels', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->char('id', 36)->unique();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->char('sample_type_id', 36)->nullable();
        $table->integer('order');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary('id');
        $table->foreign('sample_type_id')->references('id')->on('sample_types');
    });
}
```

and for the sample_types table are as follows

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sample_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->char('id', 36)->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary('id');
    });
}
```

Comment: What type is the  `sample_types.id` column?

Comment: I am fairly positive both must be of the same type. so `sample_type_id` cannot be null.

Comment: `sample_types` is being created before `levels`?

Comment: @miken32, you are right. Table levels was created before the sample_types. I am now able to generate the foreign key without any issue. Thank you. Could you  please add this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreign key statement will fail if the table being referred to does not exist yet. Ensure that you create the `sample_types` table before referring to it in the `levels` migration file.